# UIKeyboard is not added to UIWindow subviews

Tags: iphone, ios4, uikeyboard

I used to use the following code to add a UIToolbar just above the UIKeyboard and being attached to it. I just switched to the iPhone OS 4 and I realized that it's not working anymore.

```
for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

        //print all uiview descriptions

        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES) {
            .. Some code to attach the UIToolbar
        }   
    }
}
```

I realized that the code does not get into the if statement. I tried printing out all UIView descriptions just above the if and I could not see anything related to UIKeyboard. The code was working fine in OS 3.0 and 3.1. So does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are relying on undocumented behavior, it should be no surprise that it does not work in 4.0 anymore. Use your views' `inputAccessoryView` property instead, which is the documented way to do this in OS 3.2+.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use this below code:

```
  - (BOOL) findKeyboard:(UIView *) superView; 
{
    UIView *currentView;
    if ([superView.subviews count] > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < [superView.subviews count]; i++)
        {

            currentView = [superView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"%@",[currentView description]);
            if([[currentView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
            {

                NSLog(@"Find it");
                //add toolbar here

                UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -40, 100, 40)];
                UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];
                NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonItem, nil];
                [toolbar setItems:items];
                [items release];
                [currentView addSubview:toolbar];

                return YES;
            }
            if ([self findKeyboard:currentView]) return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;

}

-(void) checkKeyBoard {
    UIWindow* tempWindow;

    for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
    {
        tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];
        if ([self findKeyboard:tempWindow])
            NSLog(@"Finally, I found it");  
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self performSelector:(@selector(checkKeyBoard)) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

And you also need to add this code to function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```